# how can i open shape file in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

how can i open selected shape file in leaflet. I want the user to select a zip file and open it in the leaflet. but this codes raise error and i am using this codes to select file by users:

```
function openShapeFile() {
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.onchange = e => {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        // ------------- shape files --------------------
        var shpfile = new L.Shapefile(file, {
                onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    if (feature.properties) {
                        layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(function (k) {
                            return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
                        }).join("<br />"), {
                            maxHeight: 200
                        });
                    }
                },
                style: function (feature) {
                    return {color: 'black', fillColor: "red", fillOpacity: .75,}
                }
            }
        );
        shpfile.addTo(map);
        shpfile.once("data:loaded", function () {
            alert("finished loaded shapefile");
        });
    }
    input.click();

}
```

but it show me this error:

```
GeoJSON.js:232 Uncaught Error: Invalid GeoJSON object.
    at bi (GeoJSON.js:232:9)
    at e.addData (GeoJSON.js:118:15)
    at e.addFileData (leaflet.shpfile.js:30:23)
    at e.initialize (leaflet.shpfile.js:23:10)
    at new e (Class.js:24:20)
    at input.onchange (laboratory:117:27)
bi @ GeoJSON.js:232
addData @ GeoJSON.js:118
addFileData @ leaflet.shpfile.js:30
initialize @ leaflet.shpfile.js:23
e @ Class.js:24
```

how can i resolve this error: